# How does c++11 resolve constexpr into assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, constexpr

**The basic question:**

Edit: v-The question-v

```
class foo {
public:
    constexpr foo() { }
    constexpr int operator()(const int& i) { return int(i); }
}
```

Performance is a non-trivial issue. How does the compiler actually compile the above? I know how I *want* it to be resolved, but how does the specification actually specify it will be resolved?

1) Seeing the type int has a constexpr constructor, create a int object and compile the string of bytes that make the type from memory into the code directly?

2) Replace any calls to the overload with a call to the 'int's constructor that for some unknown reason int doesn't have constexpr constructors? (Inlining the call.)

3) Create a function, call the function, and have that function call 'int's consctructor?

**Why I want to know, and how I plan to use the knowledge**

edit:v-Background only-v

The real library I'm working with uses template arguments to decide how a given type should be passed between functions. That is, by reference or by value because the exact size of the type is unknown. It will be a user's responsibility to work within the limits I give them, but I want these limits to be as light and user friendly as I can sanely make them.

I expect a simple single byte character to be passed around in which case it should be passed by value. *I do not bar* 300mega-byte behemoth that does several minuets of recalculation every time a copy constructor is invoked. In which case passing by reference makes more sense. I have only a list of requirements that a type must comply with, not set cap on what a type can or can not do.

Why I want to know the answer to my question is so I can in good faith make a function object that accepts this unknown template, and then makes a decision how, when, or even how much of a object should be copied. Via a virtual member function and a pointer allocated with new is so required. If the compiler resolves constexpr badly I need to know so I can abandon this line of thought and/or find a new one. Again, It will be a user's responsibility to work within the limits I give them, but I want these limits to be as light and user friendly as I can sanely make them.

Edit: Thank you for your answers. The only real question was the second sentence. It has now been answered. Everything else If more background is required, Allow me to restate the above:

I have a template with four argument. The goal of the template is a routing protocol. Be that TCP/IP -unlikely- or node to node within a game -possible. The first two are for data storage. They have no requirement beyond a list of operators for each. The last two define how the data is passed within the template. By default this is by reference. For performance and freedom of use, these can be changed define to pass information by value at a user's request.

Each is expect to be a single byte long. They could in the case of metric for a EIGRP or OSFP like protocol the second template argument could be the compound of a dozen or more different variable. Each taking a non-trival time to copy or recompute.

For ease of use I investigate the use a function object that accepts the third and fourth template to handle special cases and polymorphic classes that would fail to function or copy correctly. The goal to *not* force a user to rebuild their objects from scratch. This would require planning for virtual function to preform deep copies, or any number of other unknown oddites. The usefulness of the function object depends on how sanely a compiler can be depended on not generate a cascade of function calls.

More helpful I hope?

Comment: ... Is that valid C++ syntax?

Comment: `class foo(int& i) {` is not valid.  Also, this question makes no sense.  If a `constexpr` is evaluated at compile time, it doesn't generate _any_ assembly.  If it's not evaluated at compile time, then it's 100% identical to any non-constexpr function.

Comment: Oops, I'll have to fix that, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++11 standard doesn't say anything about how constexpr will be compiled down to machine instructions. The standard just says that expressions that are constexpr may be used in contexts where a compile time constant value is required. How any particular compiler chooses to translate that to executable code is an implementation issue.

Now in general, with optimizations turned on you can expect a reasonable compiler to not execute any code at runtime for many uses of constexpr but there aren't really any guarantees. I'm not really clear on what exactly you're asking about in your example so it's hard to give any specifics about your use case.

Comment: In slightly different words referring to the OP's sample: As long the compiler is able to deduce a valid constant value for `i`, the `constexpr` will compile fine ...

Comment: You have answer the question I asked. The exact why I want to know is a long list of things depending on the thing before it. Short answer: I'm writing the simplest routing protocol template I can.

Answer (score 1):

`constexpr` expressions are not special. For all intents and purposes, they're basically `const` unless the context they're used in is `constexpr` and all variables/functions are also `constexpr`. It is implementation defined how the compiler chooses to handle this. The Standard never deals with implementation details because it speaks in abstract terms.